# google maps markers don't render on pan

Tags: google-maps

I have a few hundred markers and I noticed that they don't get rendered all at once, but rather within bounds of the viewport. 
When I set a location that does not require map refresh and the map just pans to the new location (e.g switching bounds of australia to asia), the markers don't get added to the map. However, when I manually drag the map the missing markers get rendered immediately. Is there some event I need to trigger to make markers appear/added to new bounds?

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean by switching bounds, what action are you taking when doing this? If you are manually handling events, be specific about it.

Comment: i call autosuggest for places api and get bounds of asia, and then I do map.fitBounds(asiabounds); the map pans from australia to asia. however no markers are visible in asia until I either resize my browser or drag the map.